# How to use a link list nodes to modify another linked list

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list, implementation

I'm attempting to use a linked list implementation to modify another linked list.
Here's a example of what I'm trying to do.

```
list<int>list1;
list<int>list2;

list1.push_back( 1 );   // < --- want to modify this list
list1.push_back( 2 );

list2.push_back( 1 );   // with this list
```

In short, I want to use list2 as kind of like a variable to modify list1. I've done some research seems like I can't access the nodes of the list like an array. Is there a container that allows me to easily add and remove nodes to it and compare and modify it with other containers? I was thinking sets may be an alternative, but it seems as though I can't access the values in the set either. Any help or evidence would be great. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:::

I'm looking to create a sudoku solver. I put all 81 digits ( blank and given ) into "linked list". I am now looking to remove possible candidates from each "list" that represents 1 cell.

For example
    listlist1;
    listlist2;

```
list1.push_back( 1 );  
list1.push_back( 2 );

list2.push_back( 1 );
```

I now want to use list2  like this

```
list1.remove( list2(?) );  // < -- this obviously isn't possible due to how nodes are stored.
```

I hope that clears up my question a bit. This is the way I'm using to solve simple sudokus and I'll implement a brute force technique later.

Comment: `std::deque` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by modify container with another container?

Comment: What do you mean with *modify*? Can you please give an example of the before-after states of the modified list?

Comment: I've just searched up what "deque" is. I don't think that would help as much for me since it seems to have the same functionality as a Linked list unless I'm reading from the wrong sort. OR maybe, my example isn't specific enough to explain my question. I'll edit it.

Comment: It isn't clear at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: OK, now it's clear. The answer is simple, you have to write the code to do that yourself. It's only a loop or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's is one way, no doubt there's others. It does depend on exact what you circumstance is. For instance if your lists are sorted there are better way than this.

```
list<int> list1 = ...;
list<int> list2 = ...;
for (list<int>::const_iterator i = list2.begin(); i != list2.end(); ++i)
  list1.remove(*i);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try and play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't knot what your idea of modifying container with another maybe you meant about reference. Use it as reference variable:

```
list<int> list1;
list<int>& list2 = list1;

list2.push_back(1); //<--- modifies list1
```

Or use pointer:

```
list<int> list1;
list<int>* list2 = &list1;

list2->push_back(1); //<--- modifies list1
```

Read about pointers [Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson6.html)

Comment: Or a pointer variable. I would guess that the OP is confused that there is no automatic conversion to a pointer, as you would get with an array.

Comment: I think the main problem is that I'm attempting to write a algorithm where I don't know what node may contain what value. The nodes will represent a sudoku cell and it's "candidates". But this does seem like it would help if I knew the values before hand.

Answer (score 0):

Since your lists are not too long, I think using `list::remove_if()` is your best bet here.

Use an auxiliary function:

```
bool IsInList2(int el)
{
  return std::find(list2.begin(), list2.end(), el) != list2.end();
}
```

and use it in your code:

```
list1.remove_if(&IsInList2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try also. I've never noticed the "remove_if" function when I was looking over the stl "list" library.